# ansible run list of roles with loop

Tags: variable, ansible

I have main file, that can initiate different individual roles.

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  roles:
    - role: "{{ rnames }}"
...
```

when I run individual roles, it runs fine

```
ansible-playbook -i inv initiate.yml -e rnames=install_packages
```

But what I prefer is to run multiple roles, by providing a list of roles to `rname` variable

```
ansible-playbook -i inv initiate.yml -e rnames=install_packages,config_merge
```

I tried `with_items` & `loop` constructs, but can't seem to figure out.

Comment: wouldn't a playbook that calls exactly these roles solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [include](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html#ansible-builtin-include-role-module-load-and-execute-a-role) roles in a loop. For example, you'll have to split the comma-separated list of roles

```yaml
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ rnames.split(',') }}"
```

Comment: man! that's creative. thanks a bunch.. btw ```import_role``` did not work in my case, giving error: ```ERROR! You cannot use loops on 'import_role' statements. You should use 'include_role' instead.``` so I used ```include_role```

Comment: You're welcome. Right, in the loop, it can be included only. I fixed the code. Thank you for the comment.